# Embed office form via iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I was wondering that why the office form cannot be embedded into iframe perfectly.

Like the following code

```
<iframe src="https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=Ix5rlILy0USDoDcUdHBCThkWvcx4TptKrO0BZZzx9edUMzFRTDdOMTk1NThIMEs1WFFSNzBWNFdFUi4u" style="height: 300px;">
  <p>Have you completed the survey?.</p>
</iframe>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n7e3wv6v/

It only displays the pop-up link, the users have to click the link and then fill the question on the pop-up page which is not convenient.

Is there a way to embed the whole form?

Comment: i tried making the iframe fullscreen and it worked. see [the updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/n7e3wv6v/5/)

Comment: @nikhilmehta hi, but actually I have a rigid `div` on the top of the `iframe` like this https://jsfiddle.net/qnsj1k3o/, so I can make it full screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the height and width of iframe >= 350.

```
<iframe src="https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=Ix5rlILy0USDoDcUdHBCThkWvcx4TptKrO0BZZzx9edUMzFRTDdOMTk1NThIMEs1WFFSNzBWNFdFUi4u" height="350" width="350"> 

</iframe>
```

This works! below 350 dimension it doesn't.
https://jsfiddle.net/qnsj1k3o/2/

Comment: That's weird, I still encounter the same problem in my view even I put the width large than 350px.

Comment: Actually u might be using  style for giving length? 
Dont use style attribute instead use height and width of iframe.
Don't use px just define as height="350" width="350"  .
It will work i think.